# filling an area between curves using metapost

Tags: metapost, luamplib

How could I fill the area between p2 and p3 ? I tried using the `buildcycle` macro but it didn't work.

```
path p[];
p1 = fullcircle xscaled 1.2in yscaled 0.6in;

p2 = (-1cm, 0)..(0cm, -0.2cm)..(1cm, 0) shifted up;
p3 = p2 rotatedaround(center p1, 180) shifted down cutbefore p2 cutafter p2;

fill buildcycle(p2, p3) withcolor red;

draw p1 scaled 1.2; draw p2 scaled 1.2;
draw p3 scaled 1.2;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `buildcycle` before you trim `p3` -- otherwise they do not overlap, as the error message will have said.

Here is a version with a couple of other suggested optimizations.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.%{outputformat}";
beginfig(1);
path p[];
p1 = fullcircle xscaled 1.2in yscaled 0.6in;
p2 = (-1cm, 0)..(0cm, -0.2cm)..(1cm, 0) shifted up;
p3 = p2 rotatedaround(center p1, 180) shifted down;
% scale all the paths
for i=1,2,3: p[i] := p[i] scaled 2; endfor

% now make the path round the middle
fill buildcycle(p2, p3) withcolor red;

% now trim the upper path
p3 := p3 cutbefore p2 cutafter p2;

% finally draw them all.
draw p1; 
draw p2;
draw p3;

endfig;
end.
```

Compile with with `mpost`, then use `epstopdf` or some similar tool to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
fill buildcycle(reverse p2, p3) scaled 1.2 withcolor red;
```